# Executing :mksession in vim generates error

Tags: vim

When i try and save a session using :mksession, i get the following error:

```
E190: Cannot open "Session.vim" for writing
```

I have checked the permissions for the current directory, and they are fine. (I can and have been saving my files to this directory.)

Anyone got any ideas?

I am using Gvim 64-bit , on the windows 7 os.

Thanks for any insight!

Russ

Comment: This is most likely to be a permission issue. In the mean time, `:mksession /path/to/sessionfile` should help.

Comment: That's really wild, but that did it! Typing out the full path worked. NOT giving a default did NOT! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Session.vim" seems to be created at the path of the current file you are editing.

If you are viewing a system file, in a directory where you don't have permission to write, it is likely that it won't work. If you want to be sure this is the case, try to launch vim with "sudo vim/sudo gvim" and check again if it works or not.